# Declared async function not defined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I've created an async function and used it inside another function, but I'm getting an error saying it's not used and the console says it's not defined:

[image]

Comment: you named the varaible the same overwriting the scope

Comment: the problem is in the pixels in the box `(124,102)->(228,124)` specifically, the white ones

Comment: K I'm just going to say it. There's three lines here and half of it is boiler plate `async function`.  me not copying and pasting this out isn't what's preventing anyone from helping.

Comment: @jonathanHeindl thanks for the response. You're right. If you want to write it out as an answer I can close this.

Comment: @JaromandaX hilarious and useful. Thanks.

Comment: As long as you see the humor

Comment: A picture would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your example the variable isDeployed shadows the function isDeployed and makes it unusable
renaming the variable or the function will solve the problem